# Java Stack which keeps copies of pushed elements instead of references to them

Tags: java, stack

```
Stack<Animal> myStack = new Stack<Animal>();
Animal a = new Animal();
a.setValueOfAnimal(5);
myStack.push(a);
a.setValueOfAnimal(15);
System.out.println(myStack.pop().getValueOfAnimal());
```

Above you see a sample main method.

The output will be : 15.

Is there anyway to make the object in the stack safe? I do not want the object in the stack to be modified when I modify the value of "Animal a".

Is this supported by any built - in Java class?

Comment: Any object you want the stack to make a copy of must first *be copyable*, e.g., by implementing the [`Clonable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface, which requires that it implement [`.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29). No data structure can make a copy of an object if it's not clear *how* a copy should be made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I do not want the object in the stack to be modified when I modify the
>   value of "Animal a".

Then you would have to create new instance of `Animal`.

When you add the `Animal` reference in the `Stack`, you are just storing a copy of the reference, which points to the same `Animal`. So, if you modify your `Animal` instance using original reference, it is also modified for the reference in the `Stack`.

So, you need to modify your code like this: -

```
myStack.push(a);
a = new Animal(); // Make the reference `a` point to a new instance.
a.setValueOfAnimal(15);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, unless you add `a = new Animal()` after `myStack.push(a);`.

What you could also do is provide a copy constructor:

```
public Animal(Animal someAnimal) {
    this.value = someAnimal.value;
}
```

You could then write:

```
myStack.push(new Animal(a)); //put a copy in the stack
```

Comment: But your answer is more complete ;-)

Comment: @assylias.. Yeah. I prefer to post an explanatory answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

*Nulling* references after pushing would make objects on stack safe:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.setValueOfAnimal(5);
myStack.push(a);
a = null;  // remark here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code visual flow will be as the below diagram:

[image]

Hint:
[Java parameters passing is “pass-by-value”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), the value will be the reference address in case of an object value.

Why the unexpected issue:
You update the method parameter `Animal a` data after calling `myStack.push(a);` method.

If you don't' need this behavior:

- Either nullify the reference pointer after calling `myStack.push(a);` method.
  `a = null;`
- Or you use can use the same reference name `a` to create a new object in memory
  `a = new Animal();`